# Is it necessary to encrypt application content used by mobile devices?

Tags: android, ios, encryption, aes

As the title suggests and not to sound stupid but I am not too strong on encryption/secure data in a mobile platform, I am working on an app that will be available for both Android and iOS. Here is quick overview of my setup:

Both Android and iOS apps are native to their respective OS and connect to my servers via HTTPS.  I have servers setup with Amazon Web Services and where a CA registered certificate is installed on a load balancer to check incoming requests.  The apps provide the certificates and if the connection is secure then data is processed on my apache server using PHP and stored in MySQL database.  I want all of the data in the database to be encrypted and preferably with 128-bit AES encryption.  My questions are

1.) Is it entirely necessary to encrypt the data even though the channel that the data is sent through to my database is secure?

2.) If so where is the best place to store the private key? 
** Currently I have split a private key into chunks (as constants) across multiple class files and generate the key when needed. Also, for my android app I am using Proguard to help obfuscate in the event it is decompiled

3.) What is the best method to use so that the data can be encrypted/decrypted across both platforms and possibly even on a C# .NET web application?

Thanks in advance

Comment: HTTPS/TLS encrypts the data as it traverses the network. The answer to your first question is independent of this and depends on whether you need the data that is stored in the database to be encrypted or not.  For example, health or financial data may need to be encrypted when it is stored ("at rest") as well as when it is transferrred.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for your answer.  The data for the most part is not sensitive however there may be some personal information that the user may or may not enter. In the user profiles they can enter their first & last names, phone numbers, email addresses etc. But outside of this information (and account passwords of course) the data that they post are more forum-like information and I guess could be unencrypted at rest. Which would lead to question #2 and 3

Comment: The best place to store the private key is on your server.  There should be no need to perform the encryption/decryption on the client and question #3 is off-topic for SO